# Does $\left\lVert a-b \right\rVert_\infty < \epsilon \implies (\int a-b)< \int \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$a,b$ are continuous functions.

I think this is true as constants are continuous functions but I'm not sure if it holds for all cases.

Edit: Integrated over two real numbers

Comment: Even a Clever one cannot give an answer to this question.

Comment: is the set over which you are integrating of finite measure? zero measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if the measure space is finite, otherwise you'll have only $\int (a-b) \le \int \varepsilon$ because both sides may be infinite.$\,$

Comment: That's not really correct. You need to have $\mu(X) \le 1.$

Comment: Why would you need $\mu(X) \le 1$?  We're integrating $\varepsilon$ over the same space, so as long as the measure is finite we'll be okay.

Comment: Suppose the measure space is $[0,3]$ with Lebesgue measure. Define $a\equiv 2, b\equiv 1, \epsilon =3/2.$ Then we have $\|a-b\|_\infty = 1< 3/2.$ Is it true that $\int_0^3 (a-b)\, dx < 3/2?$

Comment: No, but it is true that $\int_0^3 (a-b)dx < \int_0^3 \varepsilon dx$, which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: OK, my mistake.  Bad mistake. Stupid. Let me see if I can fix this with the voting. Yes, I turned -1 into +1.